# ArcToolbox Create Replica tool advanced options

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, arctoolbox, replication

I am trying to create a two-way Replica of my SDE database to another SDE database in ArcGIS 10.0

If I use the Create Replica wizard from the 'Distributed Geodatabase' toolbar in ArcMap I am able to replicate for single tables both schema and data.
This is possible by setting option "Check out" option for this table to "All Records" value in Advanced Create Replica Options step.
BTW default for this option is "Schema only".

When I tried the Create Replica tool from ArcToolbox I haven't found such an option.

Is there any possibility to create replica for tables for both sctructure and data via ArcToolbox?

Comment: try the CreateReplica_production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help states that some of the options are not available via toolbox.
[esri help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002700000022000000.htm)

Comment: Indeed. It looks like this option is not availiable from ArcToolbox and thus it is not possible to use ArcPy script for this task.